# Using copy() with destination created by tempnam()

Tags: php

While debugging a problem in a framework, I came across some strange behavior when using `tempnam()` to create a destination for a copied file.

Here is a reduced test case:

```
touch ('/tmp/file.txt');
file_put_contents('/tmp/file.txt', 'test');
$dst = tempnam('/tmp', 'dst');
copy('/tmp/file.txt', $dst);
var_dump(filesize($dst));
```

Obviously, I would expect the `var_dump()` at the end to output "4", since this is the size of the the source file, but instead, it always comes back as zero, meaning that the destination file is empty, although `copy()` returns true. I tested on PHP 5.4.4 and 5.3.10, with identical results.

I know that I can change my code to use `fwrite()` or some similar construct, but what I would really like to know is, why doesn't it work the way I wrote it?

**Update**

It seems that this is in fact a PHP bug, calling `clearstatcache()` before `filesize()` produces the correct result, so in fact the copy was successful either way, it's `filesize()` that is lying. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65701 and https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/459

Comment: Probably because you're using absolute paths instead of relative paths. Try using the full absolute path to it. I.e.: `/var/user/you/public_html/tmp/file.txt` or relative `../tmp/file.txt`

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't make a difference. The only thing that makes the copy work is if I append some random characters to $dst, so that it doesn't point to the path created by tmpnam()

Comment: I noticed. Sorry, I wrote that before actually testing it. I tested it now and sure enough, got back `int(0)`.

Comment: I've been tinkering at the idea and was able to get `int(4)` yet at the cost of creating two `tmp` files (*most bizarre*). Check out my pastebin file http://pastebin.com/zzgZ4R0Z

Comment: The interesting part is that it's the filesize() call on the second (and theoretically empty) file that causes the the result to be correct. This looks more and more like some strange bug in PHP itself...

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. Who ever said PHP was perfect? lol

Comment: Your update is your answer. Simply copy this to answer, and mark question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is in fact a PHP bug, calling clearstatcache() before filesize() produces the correct result, so in fact the copy was successful either way, it's filesize() that is lying. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65701 and https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/459